# Handle with dictionary in QtableWidget

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

i've in my project a CSV module that import a data from CSV file. The "generateCsvData" method convert it to a dictionary, i want to insert data into many QtableWidgets (depend on some processing and calculation). For exemple "updateData" can insert an item into a the 2nd QtableWidget's cell (24,5), the problem here, when i want execute the program and reading settings, in the debug console show me: 
{} 
None. 
I know that python reference to the first value of the global scope result = {}

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, aPath, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.delimit = '\t'
        self.fileName = ""
        self.result = {}

def generateCsvData(self, fileName):
        f = open(fileName, 'r')
        mystring = f.read()
        if mystring.count(",") > mystring.count('\t'):
            if mystring.count(",") > mystring.count(';'):
                self.delimit = ","
            elif mystring.count(";") > mystring.count(','):
                self.delimit = ";"
            else:
                self.delimit = "\t"
        elif mystring.count(";") > mystring.count('\t'):
            self.delimit = ';'
        else:
            self.delimit = "\t"
        f.close()
        f = open(fileName, 'r') 
        with f:
            f = open(fileName, 'r')
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=self.delimit)
            header=[[head] for head in next(reader)]
            for row in reader:
                key = row[0]  #####
                print(row)
                if key in self.result:
                        pass
                self.result[key] = (row [1:])
            print (self.result)

def updateData(self, k, v, n, m):
    print (self.result)
    #print("Value : %s" % self.result.get(k, "Never"))
    item = self.result.get(k)[v]
    print(item)
    newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
    newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)))
    self.ui.tableWidget_Bilan.setItem(n, m, newItem)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')
    main = MyWindow('')
    main.updateData(k="11110000", v=0, n=24, m=4)  
    main.setMinimumSize(820, 300)
    main.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

when i clicked the button to execut the "updateData" method, i get the TypeError: updateData() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'v', 'n', and 'm'. So how can i use the "updateData", or any other method after the dict will be full? any idea please, and thank you!

Comment: Are you having problems with the indentation, or it's just the markup ? updateData method should be in inside myWindow ...

Comment: The problem is, this class MyWindow from file_2.py inherits some properties  from a Class Ui_MainWindow() created by QT Designer, which had a QtableWidget as (tableWidget_Bilan) and many other QtableWidgets in file_1.py. When i execute the program, it's loading the CSV file and inserting it in the 1st QtableWidget to display the items, modified them if it necessary. My next method, that one whom convert the CSV file to a dict, it will be execute inside the loadCsv method after the load process. The  TypeError i get because the dict at the fist state is empty. I hope you understand me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

**main.py**

```
import csv
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, aPath, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(55)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(14)

        conLayout = QHBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        self.fileName = "csv.csv"                              # +
        self.result   = {}

        self.generateCsvData(self.fileName)                    # +

    def generateCsvData(self, fileName):                       # +
        with open(fileName, "r") as fileInput:                    
            for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(fileInput)):
                if i:
                    self.result[row[0]] = (row[1:])

    def updateData(self, k, v, n, m):
        [print(kk, vv) for kk, vv in self.result.items()]

        item = self.result.get(k)[v]
        print("\nitem =`{}`".format(item))

        newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
        newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)))
#        self.ui.tableWidget_Bilan.setItem(n, m, newItem)    # -
        self.tableWidget.setItem(n, m, newItem)              # +

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')
    main = MyWindow('')
    main.updateData(k="11110000", v=0, n=24, m=4)  
    main.setMinimumSize(820, 300)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**csv.csv**

```
key,    item1,  item2, item3,  item4,  item5,  item6,  item7, item8, item9, item10, item11, item12, item13
1111, Title 1,  12521, 94565,       ,       ,       , 684651,      ,      ,  44651,       ,       ,  
1112, Title 2,  65115,      , 466149,  46645, 555641,       ,      ,      , 412045,  98416,       ,  
1113, Title 3, 243968,      ,       , 466149,  46645, 555641, 98656,      ,       , 412045,  98416, 
11110000,Title 4,243968,    ,       , 466149,  46645, 555641, 98656,      ,       , 412045,  98416,
```

[image]

---

**Update**

```
import csv
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, aPath, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(55)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(14)

        button = QPushButton("Select csv file")               # +
        button.clicked.connect(self.selectCsvFile)            # +

        conLayout = QHBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        conLayout.addWidget(button)                           # +

        self.fileName = ""                                    # - "csv.csv"                           
        self.result   = {}

    def generateCsvData(self, fileName):                       
        with open(fileName, "r") as fileInput:                    
            for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(fileInput)):
                if i:
                    self.result[row[0]] = (row[1:])

        if self.result:                                       # +
            self.updateData(k="11110000", v=0, n=24, m=4)     # +   !!!         

    def updateData(self, k, v, n, m):
        if not self.result: return                            # +

        [print(kk, vv) for kk, vv in self.result.items()]

        item = self.result.get(k)[v]
        print("\nitem =`{}`".format(item))

        newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
        newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(n, m, newItem)              

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def selectCsvFile(self):
        self.fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
                           self, 
                           'Open file', 
                           '',
                           "Csv Files (*.csv)")
        if self.fileName: 
            print("\n {} \n".format(self.fileName))
            self.generateCsvData(self.fileName)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')
    main = MyWindow('')
#    main.updateData(k="11110000", v=0, n=24, m=4)            # --- !!!
    main.setMinimumSize(820, 300)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Show I use this  self.fileName = " " and creat a method to get the file, because everytime I'll load different file name ? And thank you again bro

Comment: S.Nick, i want to contact you if you want please

Comment: The problem is, this class MyWindow from file_2.py inherits some properties  from a Class Ui_MainWindow() created by QT Designer, which had a QtableWidget as (tableWidget_Bilan) and many other QtableWidgets in file_1.py. When i execute the program, it's loading a CSV file and inserting it in the 1st QtableWidget to display the items, modified them if it necessary. My next method, that one whom convert the CSV file to a dict, it will be execute inside the loadCsv method after the load process. The  TypeError i get because the dict at the fist state is empty. I hope you understand me

Comment: I added in response a second example that will suit you :)

Comment: It's working but only for self.updateData(k="11110000", v=0, n=24, m=4), i need to insert more items

Comment: @AnassBelmaati Think very well what you want to do, describe the idea, give an example of your work. But that is another question. I consider the current question closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190215/discussion-between-anass-belmaati-and-s-nick).